# Installing MongoDB via yum on AWS linux fails: HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, yum

I was trying to install `mongodb@3.4` via yum on my server by following the steps on [MongoDB Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/). First, I created a file called **mongodb-org-3.4.repo** in **/etc/yum.repos.d/** directory and copied the text as below.

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

Then I tried `sudo yum install mongodb-org` but got an error on it.

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                             | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                          | 2.3 kB     00:00
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/latest/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.



One of the configured repositories failed (MongoDB),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
packages for the previous distribution release still work).

3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
--enablerepo for temporary usage:

yum-config-manager --disable mongodb-org-3.4

4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
compromise:

yum-config-manager --save --setopt=mongodb-org-3.4.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from mongodb-org-3.4: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/latest/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

After that, I tried `yum repolist` and found out the status of **MongoDB** get 0.

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                             | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                          | 2.3 kB     00:00
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/latest/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/latest/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
nodesource/x86_64                     | 2.5 kB     00:00
repo id                repo name                       status
amzn-main/latest       amzn-main-Base                  5,668
amzn-updates/latest    amzn-updates-Base                 435
mongodb-org-3.4/latest MongoDB                             0
nodesource/x86_64      Node.js Packages for Enterprise    61
repolist: 6,164
```

I wonder whether that repo is still valid or not? Thank you~

Here's my server OS version:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2017.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2017.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2017.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Oops, sry abt that. Cause I'm used to search for any solution related to coding in Stack Overflow. Thx for your suggestion, I will try other platform to ask next time;)

Comment: I am facing similar problem. I am tring to upgrade from v3.0.11 to v3.2.20 and i already tried solution below but it's not working for me

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please try this,

sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/mongod*

sudo yum clean all

again create repo file

sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.4.repo

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

Comment: Wow~Work like a charm~Thx a lot XD

Comment: Yes. File name matters. I changed it to mongodb-org-3.4 from mongodb-org. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

**updated to March/2018**

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.6.repo
```

add (or replace) the mongo repo configuration:

```
[mongodb-org-3.6]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc
```

now, you're able to do a

`yum repolist`

and

`sudo yum install -y mongodb-org`

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to add `exclude` directory from `/etc/yum.conf` to prevent future updates
for example:

```
exclude=mongodb-org,mongodb-org-server,mongodb-org-shell,mongodb-org-mongos,mongodb-org-tools
```

But above line need to be added after perform install mongodb-org:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

---

### **So, remove the `exclude` line from `/etc/yum.conf` to make the `mongodb-org` package available**